# How to redraw SurfaceView using invalidate() metod?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I have a class `GameBoard` which extends `SurfaceView`. Inside I have an `OnDraw` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int size  = getWidth()/8;
        canvasSize = size;
        pawnBitmap[0] = bigPawn;
        pawnBitmap[1] = smallPawn;
        float left_distance;
        float top_distance;
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            for (int i =0; i < 4; i++){
                left_distance = i*size+(float)50;
                top_distance = j*size+(float)10;
                canvas.drawBitmap(pawnBitmap[0], left_distance, top_distance, paint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(pawnBitmap[1], 6*size+i*30+(float)10, top_distance+30, paint);
            }
        }

    }
```

`pawnBoard`, `bigPawn` and `smallPawn` are public in this class and they are like:

```
public BitmapFactory myBitmapFactory = new BitmapFactory();

public  Bitmap[] pawnBitmap = new Bitmap[2];
public Bitmap bigPawn =  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.game_button_2), 90, 90, false);
public Bitmap smallPawn = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.game_button_2), 30, 30, false);
```

I have also a second method in which I'm changing the image of bigPawn and smallPawn :

```
public void setBitmaps(Bitmap one, Bitmap two){
        this.paint = new Paint();
        this.bigPawn = one;
        this.smallPawn = two;
        this.tmp=4;
        invalidate();

    }
```

But after calling this method inside another (inside another class), the images are not changing. I checked using the `tmp` variable if `setBitmaps()` method really changes the images, and this is correct. But the invalidate function doesn't work. Why?
Here is how I'm calling the `setBitmaps` method:

```
public void savePermutation(View view){

        Bitmap tmpBitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blue), 230, 230, false);
        Bitmap tmpBitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blue), 100, 100, false);
        myGameBoard.setBitmaps(tmpBitmap1, tmpBitmap2);


    }
```

I was looking for the solution, but none of this which I found was helpfull.

Comment: Is the onDraw called?  Or, does it draw the wrong bitmaps?

Comment: onDraw  is 'called' when I create an instance of GameBoard, which extends SurfaceView (onDraw is a standard method for SurfaceView). And first time everything is draw correct. But after calling invalidate() inside setBitmaps method nothing is changing. I don't have any errors or warning. Application is working, but bitmaps doesn't change

Comment: OK, I'll be more precise.  After you invalidate(), is onDraw() called?

Comment: No, onDraw() is not called

Answer (score 2):

Override `surfaceCreated()`.  Then add this line:

```
setWillNotDraw(false);
```

Comment: you mean i should add this line inside surfaceCreated() method? Unfortunatelly it doesn't help

Comment: Yes I think surfaceviews do not redraw by default

Comment: thanks for help, but it didn't help, the images didn't change

Comment: This is bizarre.  You've put a breakpoint in the onDraw and it's only called when the view is first created.  Correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if i correctly understand your question. method onDraw() is like i posted above. And when I create first time the instance of Class GameBoard everything is ok - I see my images on canvas. But after calling method savePermutation() nothing changes, the images are still the same as at the beginning.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of onCreate(), super.oncreate() will do.  Now run your app in debug.  Check to see if the breakpoint is hit after invalidate().  The point is to determine if onDraw() is really not being called.  I think it is and the problem is that your bitmaps never change.